# Image over Image in Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

I want to put Image over Image, Video Thumb and Play Icon over it.
I want to put play icon in center over the video thumb image. I am using FrameLayout for it, but play icon does not view in center.

My XML File..

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageVideoThumb"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePlayIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/video_play_icon" />
</FrameLayout>
```

How can create it, please help me..

Comment: yes, because that's not what a framelayout does. it does not place items in the center. it places then in the top left corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This. Just Change in to your XML file like this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageVideoThumb"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePlayIcon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/video_play_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following code :

```
RelativeLayout rv = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_ph);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
ImageButton im1 = new ImageButton(this);

im1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lamp);
im1.setId(i);
im1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
  TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tx.setText("lamp #" + v.getId());
 }
});

 params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
 params.leftMargin = x;
 params.topMargin = y;
 rv.addView(im1, params);
```

XML Layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/my_ph"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:gravity="bottom">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/map" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_below="@+id/image" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work I think. 
Using your thumbnail image as a parent layout and setting gravity: center ,will align the play ImageView in the center of parent layout ,whose background is set as the thumbnail

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageVideoThumb"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePlayIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/video_play_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Gravity` of your `ImagesViews` to align them in center:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageVideoThumb"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="120dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePlayIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/video_play_icon" />

</FrameLayout>
```